# Vscode development, examples of language support, debugger integration

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, autocomplete

I am developing a new system level programming language. I have made good progress on the compiler. I need some direction on how to think about the following problems.

1. How do I develop language support for Vscode including syntax coloring, and auto complete.
   Are there source code examples of existing integration?
2. How do I think about debugger integration on Vscode (for Linux and Windows)?

Comment: read the doc pages for extension development, its all in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the color syntaxing in VSCode is done with TextMate rules.  Start with an existing TextMate .tmLanguage files is on GitHub. Search for a TextMate bundle for the language you are interested in and then navigate to the Syntaxes folder. The 'code' Yeoman generator can handle either .tmLanguage or .plist files. I found the following links provided the information I needed:

https://www.codemag.com/article/1809051/Writing-Your-Own-Debugger-and-Language-Extensions-with-Visual-Studio-Code

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide

https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars

You can start your own extension easily using 'Yo code' generator. Found at the link below. Use the 'code' generator from the list, and then pick New Language Support

https://yeoman.io/generators/

Create a debug adapter that implements the Debug Adapter Protocol (DAP) and communicates with the debugger engine. The debug adapter should handle requests from VSCode to start and stop debugging, set breakpoints, and retrieve variable values and call stacks